# Inverting a regex in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have this string:

```
[1] "19980213"    "19980214"    "19980215"    "19980216"    "19980217"    "iffi"        "geometry"   
[8] "date_consid"
```

and I want to match all the elements that are not dates and not "date_consid". I tried

```
res =  grep("(?!\\d{8})|(?!date_consid)", vec, value=T)
```

But I just cant make it work...

Comment: You don't need the or `|`, you want both conditions to be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```r
vec <- c("19980213", "19980214", "19980215", "19980216","19980217", "iffi","geometry", "date_consid")
grep("^(\\d{8}|date_consid)$", vec, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
## => [1] "iffi"     "geometry"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/a5N9S2)

The `^(\d{8}|date_consid)$` regex matches a string that only consists of any eight digits or that is equal to `date_consid`.

The `value=TRUE` makes `grep` return values rather than indices and `invert=TRUE` inverses the regex match result (returns those that do not match).

Answer (score 4):

The pattern that you tried gives all the matches because the lookaheads are unanchored.

Using separate statements with or `|` will still match all strings.

You can change to logic to asserting from the start of the string, what is directly to the right is not either 8 digits or date_consid in a single check.

Using a positive lookahead, you have to add `perl=T` and add an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and add an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string after the lookahead.

```
 ^(?!\\d{8}$|date_consid$)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `\\d{8}$` Match 8 digits until end of string
  - `|` Or
  - `date_consid$`Match date_consid until end of string
- `)` Close lookahead

For example

```
vec <- c("19980213", "19980214", "19980215", "19980216","19980217", "iffi","geometry", "date_consid")
grep("^(?!\\d{8}$|date_consid$)", vec, value=T, perl=T)
```

Output

```
[1] "iffi"     "geometry"
```